# Scale a fragment (FrameLayout) when another one is added next to it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-framelayout

I have a fragment that consists of an `ExpandableListView`. Now when a child is clicked, I want to add another fragment next to the ListView. The ListView should scale so the new fragment fits properly.

Here's my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.test"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
        android:background="?attr/spinner_background"
        android:gravity="center">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_menu"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
```

I add the list fragment like this:

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_menu, fragment, "fragMenu").commit();
```

And on child click I add the other fragment:

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_content, fragment, "fragContent").commit();
```

Is there any way to scale the first fragment when another one is added? Will I have to set the width programatically?

Note if I set specific width's to the 2 FrameLayouts it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is having both FrameLayout share the total space of your TableRow ?

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.test"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
    android:background="?attr/spinner_background"
    android:gravity="center">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_menu"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=1
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=1
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

Then, add this line

```
findViewById(R.id.fragment_content).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_content, fragment, "fragContent").commit();
```

This will make the second container visible, the `LinearLayout` will give equivalent space to each container automatically during layout process (because of the `layout_weight` attribute).

PS: Stop using `fill_parent`, it's deprecated since API 8 ...

Comment: Using GONE didn't even cross my mind. Also thanks for the fill_parent tip :-) Cheers!